# How do I disable Kereberos preauthentication?

Tags: debian, kerberos

I'm seeing this error message:

```
NEEDED_PREAUTH: admin@THIS.LAN for for kadmin/admin@THIS.LAN, Additional pre-authentication required
```

How do I disable Kerberos pre-authentication? 
The server and client do not have access to UDP on port 123, i.e., NTP, and I cannot change that -- and this is important for syncing the times as required by Kerberos.

---

Following up on a [reference](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-admin/Adding-or-Modifying-Principals.html) inspired by the answer below, the answer is to use `modify_principal *user* -requires_preauth` in kadmin.

Comment: Kerberos clients should automatically failover to TCP if UDP doesn't work. What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: Is this related to your home directory question? If so, what are you using for Kerberos?

Comment: [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219542/kerberos-ldap-login-fails-remove-preauth)

Comment: They are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `kadmin/admin` part of your output, I'm going to assume you're trying to run `kadmin`.

It's impossible to run `kadmin` without entering a password. Even though it's possible to disable the `requires_preauth` attribute with the `modprinc` command inside `kadmin`, `kadmin` itself does not honour that attribute and *always* requires authentication.

If you need to be able to run some `kadmin` commands without entering a password (e.g., in a script or something), use `kadmin.local`. That can only be done as root on your master KDC, though.

Comment: This wasn't a kadmin specific question - but your answer did answer the question - how to remove preauth requirements. Here: http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-admin/Adding-or-Modifying-Principals.html